# Array reduce none of those signatures are compatible with each other

Tags: typescript, reduce

I have a `tips` variable that might look like this:

```
[
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  [
    "nested one",
    "nested two",
    "nested three",
  ],
  "four",
]
```

I want to output it all on the same level.

```
[
  {
    "text": "One",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": false
  },
  {
    "text": "Two",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": false
  },
  {
    "text": "Three",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": true
  },
  {
    "text": "Nested One",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": true
  },
  {
    "text": "Nested Two",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": true
  },
  {
    "text": "Nested Three",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": false
  },
  {
    "text": "Four",
    "isHidden": true,
    "indented": false
  }
]
```

(Indented set to true on the sub-array)

I wrote this...

```
  tips.reduce((contentSoFar: ChatTip[], tip: string | string[]) => {
    // If it is just a string
    if (typeof tip == "string") {
      return [
        ...contentSoFar,
        {
          text: tip,
          isHidden: true,
          indented: false,
        },
      ];
    }
    return [
      ...contentSoFar,
      ...tip.map((t: string) => ({
        text: t,
        isHidden: true,
        indented: true,
      })),
    ];
  }, [])
```

But typescript throws this error on the reduce:

> Each member of the union type '{ (callbackfn: (previousValue: string,
> currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) =>
> string): string; (callbackfn: (previousValue: string, currentValue:
> string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string,
> initialValue: string): string; (callbackfn: (previousValue: U,
> currentValue: string, ...' has signatures, but none of those
> signatures are compatible with each other.

I'm trying to work it out, it looks like its expecting `contentSoFar` to be a string, but I thought I accounted for that with the `ChatTip[]` hint.

Comment: Consider using flatMap instead? Shorter *and* no compiler errors: https://tsplay.dev/wOL0EN

Comment: @vr. that's amazing, thank you. I even tried that first, but I think I messed something up along the way. I'll mark you correct if you answer it and want the points.